# How to tell which parameters are required and which are not? (visual c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parameters

I am following an MSDN tutorial on Visual C++ on creating windows. It's using this code to register a window class.

```
// Register the window class.
const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);
```

When I look up the WNDCLASS structure on MSDN: [WNDCLASS Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx) it gives this implementation:

```
typedef struct tagWNDCLASS {
  UINT      style;
  WNDPROC   lpfnWndProc;
  int       cbClsExtra;
  int       cbWndExtra;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HICON     hIcon;
  HCURSOR   hCursor;
  HBRUSH    hbrBackground;
  LPCTSTR   lpszMenuName;
  LPCTSTR   lpszClassName;
} WNDCLASS, *PWNDCLASS;
```

How can you tell by the documentation that you only need these three parameters?

1. lpfnWndProc
2. hInstance
3. lpszClassName

Comment: It's a `struct` and it needs *all* members be filled in. Some of them can be `0` or `NULL` of course, which is documented in the link you posted.

Comment: Perhaps by reading it? For example: *hCursor* A handle to the class cursor. This member must be a handle to a cursor resource. **If this member is NULL, an application must explicitly set the cursor shape whenever the mouse moves into the application's window.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parameters are required, but most of them can be set to default values.

```
WNDCLASS wc;
wc.style = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wc.hIcon = NULL;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
wc.lpszClassName = "MYCLASS";
```

Comment: I think what the OP overlooked is that `WNDCLASS wc = { };` initially sets all members to `0`. There is a significant difference between `you only need these three parameters` and `you only need to **override** the default 0/NULL values for these three parameters`.

Comment: @dxiv I didn't realize the wc = { }; sets all members to 0 but I see now how that works.